# VueJs v-bind:type on input element not working not working when using type as property name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <x :type="type"></x>
  </div>

  <script>
     Vue.component('x', {
         props    : ['type'],
         template : '<input>'
     });

     const x = new Vue({
         el   : '#app',
         data : {
             type : `password`,
         },
     })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why wont `:type="type"` work here in this scenario and create and element like so : `<input type="password">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you defined `type` as a prop, it won't be automatically applied to the root element. You need to bind it in your template:

```
Vue.component('x', {
  props    : ['type'],
  template : '<input :type="type">'
});
```

Any parent scope attribute bindings that are not recognized as props will be applied to the root element automatically, so alternatively you can just remove the `type` prop and rely on this default behavior instead:

```
Vue.component('x', {
  props    : [],
  template : '<input>'
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to bind once only in component or do I have to do it in component and root element?

Comment: The point of props is it allows some data to be passed to a component and then that component can choose to do whatever it wants with that data, in your case you want to assign it to the `type` attribute on the root element. So it depends on what you want to do. Typically you always need to bind it twice, but in the second example in my answer you don't need to do anything in the child.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly specify type prop on template:

```
Vue.component('x', {
     props    : ['type'],
     template : '<input :type="type">'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <x :type="type"></x>
  </div>

  <script>
     Vue.component('x', {
         props    : ['type'],
         template : `<input :type="type">`
     });

     const x = new Vue({
         el   : '#app',
         data : {
             type : `password`,
         },
     })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed the `type` prop but didn't bind in template. Try a bit the following code

```js
Vue.component('x', {
    props    : ['type'],
    template : '<input :type="type">'
});

const x = new Vue({
    el   : '#app',
    data : {
        type : `password`,
    },
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <x :type="type"></x>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why i have to bind twice,  once in `Vue.component` and again  in `<x :type="type">`, can you please enlighten me?

Comment: You are not binding twice. In `<x :type="type">` you are just passing the `type` to `x` component (can consider a function call like x({type: 'type'})). In `x` component's template you are binding  `<input :type="type">`. For more see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html